# style border-spacing accumulates spacing and border even after element remove

Tags: jquery, html, css

Thanks for reading.

I have this html fragment

```
<div class="table">
    <!--1st row --->
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell_medium table_cell">Nickname</div>
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">-</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--2nd row --->
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell_medium table_cell">Nickname</div>
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">-</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--3rd row --->
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell_medium table_cell">Nickname</div>
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">-</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--4th row --->
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell_medium table_cell">Nickname</div>
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">-</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--5th row --->
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell_medium table_cell">Nickname</div>
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">-</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--6th row --->
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell_medium table_cell">Nickname</div>
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">-</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--7th row --->
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell_medium table_cell">Nickname</div>
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">-</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--8th row --->
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell_medium table_cell">Nickname</div>
    <div class="cell_short table_cell">-</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>​
```

And this style

```
.table {
border-spacing: 2px 1px;
background-color: black;
width: 316px;
}
.table_cell {
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
background-color: red;
}
.cell_short {
width: 80px;
text-align: center;
}
.cell_medium {
width: 150px;
text-align: center;
}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XhC9X/3/)

As you can see I have a table with several rows. Every cell of a row has border-spacing: 2px 1px. When I am trying to remove a row from DOM say with jquery, removes the entire row but keeps the border-spacing: 2px 1px. If I remove several rows the border-spacing: 2px 1px accumulates and leave behind a large space. I do not know if this is trivial but I was unable to find anything relative.

Can anyone en-light me why is this happening?

Comment: Always include the relevant markup, code, and styles **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: I update the question accordingly, if anyone actually knows I will much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Without giving us the javascript script, it will be hard to guess the problem.

Anyway, why are you not creating a table instead of creating tones of divs?

If your goal is to get a table, use a table. It will also be much easier to tune in your css!! And much easier to modify afterwards with javascript.

learn tables : http://www.quackit.com/html/html_table_tutorial.cfm

Once you have your table, simply put a different id to each row (`<tr id=row_numb>...</tr>`), and with javascript, you'll be able to remove the wanted row.

As a result, your bug will disappear (css will always follow), and you'll have a cleaner code.

Comment: It does not matter the way you are going to delete the row..In my case I just use $('..').remove(); I discovered that the problem appears only in Chrome, so I guess its a browser specific problem/behavior